# React-native Android 10 Agora SDK RtcEngine.create is never resolved

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, agora.io

package.json

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-agora": "^3.3.2",
```

Starting the engine code

```
    async _createEngine() {
            this._engine = await RtcEngine.create(AGORA_ID); // AGORA_ID is a string
            this._setListeners();
    }
```

but the this._setListeners(); method is never executed

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error, can you double check your AGORA_ID variable?